# screen freezes while running without debug

Tags: android, android-asynctask

In my Android app, we have a Autocomplete textview. We get the values to ve displayed to the autocomplete textview from Database (mysql accessed using Php scripts). The database returns around 45 values.
In my android app I have a asynctask which reads the value and onPostexecute im binding the values to the autocomplete area textview.

My Problem is when I debug and set breakpoints in my onPostExecute or somewhere the app works perfectly. When i run without debugging the screen freezes and does nothing. I don;t have a clue what's wrong here. Any anyone help!!

My ASynctask:

```
 public class AsyncGetCityList extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> 
  {
    String orderdetailsurl = "URL for my DB";

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        String method = params[0];
        if (method.equals("getCityList")) {
            //String mobilenumber = params[1];
            String result = null;

            try {
                URL reseturl = new URL(orderdetailsurl);
                HttpURLConnection loginconnection = (HttpURLConnection) reseturl.openConnection();
                loginconnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                loginconnection.setDoOutput(true);
                loginconnection.setDoInput(true);
                OutputStream loginos = loginconnection.getOutputStream();
                BufferedWriter loginbw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(loginos, "UTF-8"));
                // loginbw.write(data);
                loginbw.flush();
                loginbw.close();

                InputStream loginis = loginconnection.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader loginbr = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(loginis, "iso-8859-1"));
                String response = "";
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                String line = "";
                while ((line = loginbr.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line + "\n");
                }
                result = sb.toString();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // Oops
            } finally {

            }
            return result;
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result)
    {
        android.os.Debug.waitForDebugger();
        if (result == null) {
            final android.app.AlertDialog.Builder alertdialog = new android.app.AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
            alertdialog.setMessage("Please check your Internet Connection!!!");
            alertdialog.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                    Intent intent = getIntent();
                    finish();
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            });

            alertdialog.setTitle("Warning").create();
            alertdialog.show();
        }  else {
            getCityJSON = result;
            ShowCityList();
            //progressView.dismiss();

        }
    }
}

protected void ShowCityList() {
    try
    {
        JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(getCityJSON);
        cityJSONArray = jsonObj.getJSONArray(TAG_RESULT);
        areas=new String[cityJSONArray.length()];
        for (int i = 0; i < cityJSONArray.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject c = cityJSONArray.getJSONObject(i);
            String City=c.getString(TAG_CITY);
         areas[i]=City;
    }

        arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
            this, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, areas);
        autocompletearea.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

        autocompletearea.setThreshold(1);

        autocompletearea.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                autocompletearea.showDropDown();
            }
        });
        autocompletearea.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus)
            {
                autocompletearea.showDropDown();
            }
        });


        autocompletearea.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                InputMethodManager in = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                in.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getApplicationWindowToken(), 0);
                String selection = (String) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
                for (int i = 0; i < areas.length; i++) {
                    if (areas[i].equals(selection)) {
                        pos = i;
                        break;
                    }
                }

                System.out.println("Position " + pos); //check it now in Logcat

                city=autocompletearea.getText().toString();

                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getPreferences(0).edit();

                session.setcityselectedpreference(MainActivity.this,"cityselected","1");
                int selectedPosition = parent.getSelectedItemPosition();
                editor.putInt("spinnerSelection", pos);
                editor.commit();

            }
        });

        SharedPreferences prefs = getPreferences(0);
        String cityselectedsession=session.getcityselectedPreference(this,"cityselected");
        if(cityselectedsession.equals(""))
        {
            autocompletearea.setText("");
        }
        else if(cityselectedsession.equals("1")) {
            autocompletearea.setText(areas[prefs.getInt("spinnerSelection", 0)]);
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you debug your app, the system not only takes you to a specific method but will make you travel to every single method being used in order to finish a specific method. Of crouse, it's your choice whether you want to press `F8` again and again or press `F9` and jump to another break point. The reason why your phone freezes during debugging process is because

1. Async Task is kind of a thread.
2. Fetching data from DataBase isn't an easy task for your phone.

Thus you should avoid placing breakpoints under long loops or threads and of course for the task which requires a lot of computation.
If you want to check values, you should go for

[Logs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html)

Logs are similar to `System.out.println();` i.e. it allows you to look at the response in **AndroidLogcat** or **AndroidMonitor**(If you are using AS Version < 3)

Also
If you were testing on an emulator, it's a very bad idea. You need to have a really good Desktop for that. Like 16Gigs of RAM, an i7 processor, in case of Linux or Windows. Emulators are slow. Use a real phone. Your phone won't freeze as much as your emulator does.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! but the actual problem i face is When i give "Run app (Shift+F10) the app freezes in my emulator. As you said, while debugging im giving F9 and jumping to another thread. But my screen freezes during a normal run, i mean if I just run my app. Hope I made my point clear :(

Comment: Oh, so you were testing on an emulator. Well, it's a very bad idea. You need to have a really good Desktop for that. Like 16Gigs of RAM, an i7 processor. Emulators are slow. Use a real phone. Your phone won't freeze as much as your emulator does.

Comment: I have connected my phone and tried running the app, the same happened (my screen freezes). I have tried writing a Log as you suggested in every line possible,it is going till my onPostExecute. But the log statement inside the if else loop of onPostExecute was not printed.